# SDL text rendering access violation

Tags: sdl, access-violation, sdl-2, text-rendering

I'm using SDL 2.0 with C++ for 2D graphics, compressed image format loading, sound playback and so on. Consider the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO);
    SDL_Window *pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Access Violation", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 1920, 1080, SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
    SDL_Renderer *pRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(pWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    Mix_Init(0);
    Mix_OpenAudio(44100, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 2048);
    Mix_Music *pMusic = Mix_LoadMUS("music.wav");


    TTF_Init();
    TTF_Font *pFont = TTF_OpenFont("font.ttf", 28);

    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event ev;
    while(!quit)
    {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&ev) != 0)
        {
            switch(ev.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                quit = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(pRenderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(pRenderer);

        for(int i = 0; i < 864; i++)
        {
            SDL_Color clr = { 0, 0, 0 };
            SDL_Surface *pSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(pFont, "Hey!", clr);
            SDL_Texture *pTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(pRenderer, pSurface);
            SDL_Rect dstrect = { (int)(i/27) * 60, (i%27)*40, pSurface->w, pSurface->h };
            SDL_RenderCopy(pRenderer, pTexture, 0, &dstrect);
            SDL_DestroyTexture(pTexture);
            SDL_FreeSurface(pSurface);
        }

        SDL_RenderPresent(pRenderer);
    }


    TTF_CloseFont(pFont);
    Mix_FreeMusic(pMusic);

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(pRenderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(pWindow);

    Mix_CloseAudio();
    Mix_Quit();

    IMG_Quit();
    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

What this basically does is that it just initializes SDL, loads a music, loads a font, and fills continuously the whole screen with text. Fine.

But!

If I add this line

```
...
SDL_Event ev;

Mix_PlayMusic(pMusic, 0);

while(!quit)
...
```

right here, text redrawing in the cycle

```
for(int i = 0; i < 864; i++)
{
...
}
```

starts to behave unpredictably. One of the SDL's function will shoot an access violation, after some time - between 1 and 30 seconds after start. On the other hand, would I omit text redrawing, music is playing fine.

Any ideas? Of course, all return values are checked. I've omitted checks because of the clarity of the code.

EDIT: Typos.

Comment: Anyone? Maybe I have to compile the libs?

Comment: What line does the debugger tell you is the problem?

Comment: Verify that you have 2.0 versions of `SDL_ttf` and `SDL_mixer`. Previous versions are not compatible with SDL2.

Comment: Martin: either CreateTextureFromSurface, RenderCopy, DestroyTexture or FreeSurface.

Comment: keltar: I have SDL 2.0.3, image 2.0.0, mixer 2.0.0, ttf 2.0.12; all x86. These should be the newest. I'm unable to download the same 2.0.0 version for all libs, but this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Waigh I've compiled this code and it works fine, as it should be. Are you sure you running the same code? What you're talking about is very likely to be memory corruption (either heap or stack), but that code is very unlikely to produce such corruption.